# ""tokens=2" was unexpected at this time." error message when reading 2nd word from a string

Tags: batch-file

I have a loop variable %%P containing the string **"&&";"XMLWrirter";"class";"&&"** 
WHEN I read the second word ie. "XMLWrirter" , I am getting the error ""tokens=2" was unexpected at this time."

```
for "tokens=2" %%y in %%P do (
            set "grepstr=grep -l %%y %%K"
                )
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues:

- you need to state switch `/F`, otherwise options like `tokens` are not supported;
- the set of for (the part after the `in` keyword) must be within parenthesis;
- your string in `%%P` contains `&&` which is a conditional command separator; for this not to cause trouble I recommend to use `usebackq` option;

The following should work:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims=;" %%y in ('%%P') do (
  set "grepstr=grep -l %%y %%K"
)
```

Comment: Aah, Just was wandering what exactly the OP wants.

Comment: @aschipfl: Thanks for your help. This is what I was searching for. Except, I had to use delims=; since my strings were ; separated. Could you please tell me what is this usebackq?

Comment: You're welcome! I just added the `delims=;` option to my answer for the sake of completeness... `usebackq` defines the treatment of quotes in the set of `for /F`, that is the part after the `in` keyword; since your string contains `"` I used `usebackq` so a literal string can be given enclosed in `'`, to not interfere with the `"` in your string (without the `usebackq` option I had to enclose a literal string in `"`); type `for /?` in command prompt and read the help for details;